# Whats the best way replace instance without downtime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have problem with deployment of new version of application: timeout error, app is not updated(but app still functioning)

I have an idea to check if amazon tools on server is working correctly. In order to accomplish that, i need to launch new instance and terminate old(so it will be without downtime)

Whats the best way replace instance without downtime?

P.S. timeout was max(30 min, on instance in logs no information about new deployment at all)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way IMHO to replace your instances with zero downtime is to use URL swap; which is a simple operation of exchanging CNAMEs between two ready environments.

[Read more at AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html)

**Deploying Versions with Zero Downtime (Short version)**

1. Copy Alpha environment configuration.
2. Create Omega environment based on Alpha configuration.
3. Ensure that Omega environment is functioning as expected using your hosts file (obtain IP by pinging your Elastic Beanstalk provided URL i.e *omega.elasticbeanstalk.com*).
4. Swap URL's
5. Test Omega and ensure that Alpha monitoring reports zero traffic.
6. Terminate your Alpha instances in the EC2 interface forcing a rebuild of the instances.
7. Wait for the rebuild to complete and swap back the URL's
8. Terminate the Omega environment

Comment: it make sense, i heard about it, thanks for the instructions, George

Answer (score 1):

Replacing instances using a URL swap is not always simple. You might have custom environment configuration set that you need to copy across to the new environment. Also there might be security group settings that also need to be changed for the new environment to work properly.

Rather than adjusting the auto scaling settings, I suggest temporarily changing the instance size. E.g. moving from t2.micro > t2.small and then back. This will swap all the instances with each change.

Yes, you will be charged slightly more for the 10-20 minutes it takes to swap! However it should be insignificant really.

Comment: Will it add these small instances at first and then stop the micro or shut down all micro and start small at the same time?(in this case we will have downtime)

Comment: It will temporarily double your autoscalling min size value, and add all the new servers. Then when they are ready it will shutdown the old ones. So there will be no downtime. :)

Answer (score 0):

So the easiest way was to increase 2 times min number of instances and descrease, so the new ones will stay up and the old ones will be terminated

Comment: Although this method works, I have had time when I spent 2 hours adding and removing instances but the one in question remained.

You got lucky.

Comment: When you have only 2 instances its about 50% chance that amazon will remove which you want:)

Comment: The termination policy within EC2 can be configured so `OldestInstance` is terminated first (within an autoscaling group): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/AutoScalingBehavior.InstanceTermination.html

Comment: Its a big pain in the ass to find the autoscaling group name for a Beanstalk application if you have many such configurations, and its equally difficult to figure out the correct syntax for AWS CLI, so here's what I pieced together: `ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag-value,Values=Case-Sensitive-EC2-Instance-Name-Here --query "Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[
?Key=='aws:autoscaling:groupName'].Value[]"`